# Automaticly run xinit from rc.local as different user

Tags: linux, bash, shell, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm working on some tuning of my raspberry pi b+. So I decided that midori should start automaticly after autologin. With startx it works without problems, but X is still to ressource hungry. So I'll start midori with xinit and matchbox.

As test, I use as user "pi" this command "xinit ./home/pi/startmidori.sh" and it works. So I'll put this into my rc.local file.

There is the command "su -l pi -c xinit ./home/pi/startmidori.sh", this doesn't work. I don't know why, but xinit exit immediately after starting. There's no errors or warning in Xorg logfile, but the known one (module g3d_23 not found).

How can I solve this? In guides I found some kind of solution, but all of them don't work. I tryed to run it as root but it doesn't work, too. I've no idea why.

Comment: If X is resource hungry, I am not sure how changing _startx_ _xinit_ would help at all? After all, `startx` is practically the same as `xinit ~/.xinitrc` ...

Comment: So, instead of call su -l pi -c xinit blabla, I call su -l pi -c startx, and put in /home/pi/.xinitrc the content of startmidori.sh (which is: xset -dpms xset s off xset s noblank matchbox-window-manager & midori -e Fullscreen) or can I add a path to a .sh file in .xinitrc?

Comment: update: okay adding the .sh file to xinitrc and changing the su command from xinit to startx works pretty well. but i don't understand why the xinit ./home/pi/startmidori.sh with su -l pi -c not works, but as pi user it's fine. Is it a behavior from xinit?

Comment: @user3048888 to exit the browser i use CTRL + ALT + F1, but how can i close/exit the startx in the console? Any idea? CTRL + C is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of xinit use startx.

Open rc.local

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

and use

```
su -l pi -c startx /home/pi/startmidori.sh
```

This solution works for me if i us the PiTFT, but if i connect a display via HDMI it start's only the GUI/Desktop but not Midori.

Answer (score 0):

With last version of Raspbian (RaspiOS), you need the next steps

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-legacy xinit xterm
```

Add permissions to **Anybody**

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg-legacy
```

Verify that the user is in the next groups:

```
adm dialout cdrom sudo audio video plugdev games users input netdev spi i2c gpio
```

If you launch from **rc.local** xinit or startx, start it with the user:

```
 sudo su -l newuser -c "xinit"
```